# QueryDSL how to write "WHERE ? BETWEEN col1 AND col2"

Tags: querydsl

How can I write `WHERE` clause which is something like `WHERE ? BETWEEN col1 AND col2` with QueryDSL? I know I can write as follows instead,

```
...
.where(mytable.col1.loe(constant), mytable.col2.goe(constant))
...
```

But using `BETWEEN` makes the query more readable.

I use QueryDSL 3.2.3.

---

**UPDATE:**

I ended up with something like this ([A testcase which runnable via `mvn test`](https://github.com/lbtc-xxx/querydsl-sandbox/blob/master/src/test/java/sandbox/QueryDslBetweenTest.java#L44-L60)):

```
final int constant = 10;
final QMyTable m = QMyTable.myTable;
final SimpleExpression<Boolean> operation = Expressions.operation(Boolean.class, Ops.BETWEEN,
        Expressions.constant(constant), m.col1, m.col2);

// This yields:
// SELECT ID, COL1, COL2 FROM MYTABLE WHERE ((? BETWEEN COL1 AND COL2) = ?)
// bind => [10, true]
final MyTable actual = new JPAQuery(em).from(m).where(operation.eq(true)).uniqueResult(m);
```

It works anyway but the part `= ?` is redundant. I want more simple one something like:

```
SELECT ID, COL1, COL2 FROM MYTABLE WHERE (? BETWEEN COL1 AND COL2)
```

I have no idea how to write it. Is there any way to construct this query via QueryDSL?

Comment: You could [create a constant expression](/questions/7661770/how-to-create-constant-numeric-value-expression-in-querydsl) and use its `between` method. Does that work?

Comment: @Rhymoid Hi, thank you the info. I have just investigated about it and edited the question and added another question. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @Rhymoid I found the answer. Thank you for your help! http://stackoverflow.com/a/40759823/3591946

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just found this:

```
final int constant = 10;
final QMyTable m = QMyTable.myTable;
final BooleanExpression operation = Expressions.booleanOperation(Ops.BETWEEN,
        Expressions.constant(constant), m.col1, m.col2);

// This yields:
// SELECT ID, COL1, COL2 FROM MYTABLE WHERE (? BETWEEN COL1 AND COL2)
// bind => [10]
final MyTable actual = new JPAQuery(em).from(m).where(operation).uniqueResult(m);
```

This constructs one which I was exactly looking for.

Testcase: https://github.com/lbtc-xxx/querydsl-sandbox/blob/master/src/test/java/sandbox/QueryDslBetweenTest.java

Comment: Doesn't `Expressions.constant(constant).between(m.col1, m.col2)` work?

Comment: It produces a compilation error due to `Expression` doesn't have the method `between()`, [at least with QueryDSL 3.2.3](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.3/apidocs/com/mysema/query/types/Expression.html).